# Why is vendor bill not saving on update?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am able to successfully create vendor bills in my script, but for some reason, when I am attempting to save updates/edits to the same vendor bills it will come up with an error message: "Please enter value(s) for: Vendor". Does anyone have any insight to why this may be occurring? I am setting the vendor under the "entity" field like so (in both the update and create calls), and the code is the same for both contexts (in the portion where the fields are set), with a valid internal ID being set for the sellerVendorId value:

```
vendorBill.setValue('entity', sellerVendorId);

// then saving the vendor bill
vendorBill.save();
```

Comment: Vendors can be hidden from some subsidiaries.  Check the help for the `PRIMARY SUBSIDIARY` field in the Vendor record.

Comment: Thanks, it ended up being subsidiary related, as I was setting subsidiary after vendor mistakenly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are forgetting to pass through the necessary fields of the setValue object.

vendorBill.setValue({
fieldId: 'entity', 
value: sellerVendorId
});